# Groupby and loop Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My DataFrame:

```
Id | date | date_2
1   2020-02-19   2020-02-18
1   2020-02-18   2020-02-17
1   2020-02-17   2020-02-16
2   2020-02-19   2020-02-24
2   2020-02-24   2020-02-12
etc.
```

I would like to choose date "2020-02-19" in each Id and also give me next next date 2

```
Id | date | date_2
1   2020-02-19   2020-02-17
2   2020-02-19   2020-02-12
etc.
```

Comment: can you clarify what next next means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df.assign(date_2=df['date_2'].shift(-1)).loc[df['date'].eq('2020-02-19')]
```

**Output**

```
   Id        date      date_2
0   1  2020-02-19  2020-02-17
3   2  2020-02-19  2020-02-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the index into date format by datetime index, and then usage of sort() might be a starter.

Comment: @jacobp can you please try yourdataframe.sort_values(by=['date'])? Otherwise I am thinking groupby() might work. If all this doesn't help. I'll have to check tomorrow. Its late here in Germany (:

Comment: You set the index df['date' ] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d'), then set df.set_index('date').  Instead of writing pandas. you use whatever shortform you imported. Also, 'date' is called date because your column is named date.